# Does a Daikin AC remember the settings when it was last turned on, or what the remote is set to on power-on?

Tags: air-conditioning

This is a very specific question that I've been trying to wrap my head around and can't figure out.

I have a Daikin Air Conditioner that has a "human sensor" which automatically switches to "low-power" mode when it does not detect a human presence for 20 minutes in order to save energy in case you forget to turn it off.

When I set this feature using the standard remote control that comes with the unit, the icon for that feature lights up on the LCD screen of the remote.  That feature seems to be saved permanently because if I turn the air con off, the icon still appears on the remote's LCD screen, and when I turn it on again, the icon is still there.  So unless I turn that feature off, it stays permanently on, which is to be expected. The "Econo" mode feature does not do this, for example, and its icon turns off after you turn off the air con, so if you turn on the air con again and want "Econo" mode again, you have to press the button again.

Now, I need to get a Universal Remote for Air Cons for this unit, and was trying to figure out how I could use the Universal Remote to ONLY allow for "on/off" and "change in temperature", while leaving the "human sensor" permanently on.

**So my question is this:  if I use the standard Daikin remote to turn (and leave permanently on) the "human sensor", but then use the Universal Remote to simply control the on/off and temperature setting, will the "human sensor" continue to stay activated, or will it be deactivated since the Universal Remote does not know how to send that particular signal?****

Answer (score 1):

I read the manual for your AC and it did not contain any information which could answer your question. I will guess and say that your AC will remember the "Intelligent eye" setting through a power cycle.

Why not just use your Universal Remote to turn the AC off and on and see how it behaves? There is an "Intelligent eye" indicator on the cooling unit so you can quickly see what mode the AC is in.

You don't give any details on the Universal Remote you are using, but the ones I am familiar with tend to be programmable. So if you do need the Universal Remote to send a command to set the "Intelligent eye" feature on, you should be able to program the UR to do so.